# Fastest way to create a vector of multiplication of two successive numbers

Tags: r

What's the fastest way to create a vector of elements `i * (i-1)` for `i = 1` to `i = n` in R?

Comment: Actaully the answer if very easy by inspection , ...  0. (Since the second term for the first instance is 0.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure there may be a faster solution using `Rcpp`, but for simplicity using base R

```
n <- 5
x <- seq_len(n)
x[-1] * x[-n]
## [1]  2  6 12 20
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this perhaps:

```
x = 1:10
x[-1] * x[-length(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a base function to do this already:

```
cumprod(x)
```